# Rmpi can not spawn process across nodes

Tags: openmpi

I followed the instruction here "http://math.acadiau.ca/ACMMaC/Rmpi/sample.html". Here is my R code

```
library("Rmpi")
mpi.spawn.Rslaves()
.Last <- function(){
if (is.loaded("mpi_initialize")){
    if (mpi.comm.size(1) > 0){
        print("Please use mpi.close.Rslaves() to close slaves.")
        mpi.close.Rslaves()
    }
    print("Please use mpi.quit() to quit R")
    .Call("mpi_finalize")
    }
}
mpi.remote.exec(paste("I am",mpi.comm.rank(),"of",mpi.comm.size()-1,"on",mpi.get.processor.name()))
mpi.close.Rslaves()
mpi.quit()
```

And in the script I designated the process number:

```
#$ -S /bin/sh
#$ -pe orte 20
#$ -cwd
#$ -V
#$ -o /data1/users/liuyang/R/rmpi.o
#$ -e /data1/users/liuyang/R/rmpi.e
mpiexec -np 1 R --slave CMD BATCH rmpi.R
```

But I found the R code only run on the master node, and mpi.spawn.Rslaves() only spawn 12 processes(cpu core number of the master node).

The cluster is a sge cluster, and I installed Rmpi package with openmpi version 1.4.3. So what's the reason?

I also tried to comment the mpi.spawn.Rslaves() line in the R code and changed the parameter of mpiexec to "-np $NSLOTS", but it gave no slave process error.

Comment: -np will remain 1.  R is supposed to get the number of slots from the hostfile that is passed to it automatically when things are working right.

Answer (score 0):

You need keep the mpi.spawn.Rslaves() in your R script and then run your R script by mpiexec/mpirun with "-machinefile" and "-np 1" (http://linux.die.net/man/1/mpirun) or run your R scripts by a batch scheduler such as SGE, OpenLava and so on.

Basically RMPI calls MPI API of MPI_Comm_spawn() to spawn working node. The API of MPI_Comm_spawn() gets the size and machine list from MPI context. If the RMPI scripts is executed without mpiexec/mpirun, it is Singleton MPI_INIT mode which has max ncores of the host in MPI context. If the RMPI scripts is executed with mpiexec/mpirun, the MPI context will be prepared by mpiexec/mpirun with machine list. In above case, the MPI context has machines and slots specified in machinefile. The "-np 1" means only create one instance of R script which is MPI master.